# Как написать телеграмм бота который будет в 21 00 по мск отправлять сообщение?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Как написать телеграмм бота который будет в 21 00 по мск отправлять сообщение?

Comment: Например: написать скрипт, который будет запускаться в 21:00 по мск и отправлять сообщение

Answer (score 2):

Для того, чтобы написать телеграм-бота, который будет отправлять сообщение в определенное время, можно использовать библиотеку python-telegram-bot и модуль schedule.

Пример кода:

```
import telegram
import schedule
import time

# Указываем id бота и токен
bot = telegram.Bot(token='YOUR_TOKEN')
chat_id = 'YOUR_CHAT_ID'

# Функция, которая будет отправлять сообщение
def send_message():
    message = 'Сообщение, которое нужно отправить в 21:00'
    bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=message)

# Задаем время отправки сообщения
schedule.every().day.at("21:00").do(send_message)

# Бесконечный цикл для проверки расписания
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

В этом примере бот будет отправлять сообщение каждый день в 21:00 по московскому времени. Вы можете изменить текст сообщения, время отправки и другие параметры в соответствии с вашими потребностями.

Answer (score 0):

Можно более длинным, но не менее эффективным таким способом

```
import argparse
import logging
import pytz
import telegram
import telegram.ext
import datetime


MOSCOW_TZ = pytz.timezone('Europe/Moscow')
DAYS_OF_WEEK = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) # Каждый день недели
TARGET_TIME = datetime.time(hour=21, minute=0, second=0, tzinfo=MOSCOW_TZ) # Целевое время для отправки сообщения


class TelegramBot:
    def __init__(self, token, chat_id):
        self.bot = telegram.Bot(token=token)
        self.chat_id = chat_id

    def send_message(self, message_text):
        self.bot.send_message(chat_id=self.chat_id, text=message_text)


class Scheduler:
    def __init__(self, job_queue, target_time, days_of_week):
        self.job_queue = job_queue
        self.target_time = target_time
        self.days_of_week = days_of_week

    def schedule_job(self, job):
        # Запускаем задание каждый день в целевое время
        self.job_queue.run_daily(job, self.target_time, days=self.days_of_week)


def configure_logging():
    logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)


def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--bot-token', required=True, help='Telegram Bot API token')
    parser.add_argument('--chat-id', required=True, help='Chat ID to send the message to')
    return parser.parse_args()


def main():
    args = parse_args()

    # Создаем объект бота и передаем токен и идентификатор чата
    bot = TelegramBot(args.bot_token, args.chat_id)

    # Создаем очередь заданий
    job_queue = telegram.ext.JobQueue()

    # Создаем объект планировщика и передаем очередь заданий, целевое время и дни недели
    scheduler = Scheduler(job_queue, TARGET_TIME, DAYS_OF_WEEK)

    # Создаем задание для отправки сообщения
    def send_message_job(context):
        bot.send_message('Привет, мир!')

    # Планируем задание на выполнение
    scheduler.schedule_job(send_message_job)

    # Создаем объект Updater и передаем токен, используем контекст и настраиваем очередь заданий
    updater = telegram.ext.Updater(token=args.bot_token, use_context=True)
    updater.job_queue = job_queue

    # Настраиваем логирование
    configure_logging()

    # Запускаем бота
    updater.start_polling()

    # Бот будет работать до остановки программы
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Как прекрасно, буквально несколько часов назад захотел сделать то же саоме и о чудо, ответ уже есть.
Подскажите пожалуйста, я сделал всё как вы сказали, но мне выдаёт ошибку. "RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Bot.send_message' was never awaited bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=message) RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback"